"How to Answer" help page could use some references to code
Stack Overflow's version of How to Answer doesn't mention the word "code" once. I'd love to see an excerpt about code-only answers somewhere in there.
I don't know exactly what would belong, so this is mostly boilerplate, but something like this might be fine:

Add more than just code
Code is an essential part of many good answers, but it's not the only essential part. When possible, please pair your code with a detailed explanation, including (but not limited to) what you changed and why you changed it.


Is this a thing? I assumed it was possible because of the different copies of /help/gen-ai-policy, but I wasn't totally sure.

I'd expand the last sentence with something in the spirit of "Even if the workings of code seems obvious to you, that may not be the case for less experienced users."

I would prefer having a positive approach mentioning that explanations etc make a good post, not a negative approach starting from code-only. The negative approach easily makes bad content seem okay by noting everything else optional. Even if the current draft has one sentence to clarify code is optional, all the rest heavily goes towards emphasising how important code is an even implies code-only is okay; "what you changed and why you changed it" also applies only to a very limited set of Q&A.

For example, a paragraph listing some important features of good answers would highlight options without focusing on one. Aside from example code, obvious contenders are including explanations and important references.

FWIW, the "How to Answer" is the exact same on some other SE pages I just checked. It doesn't seem to be adjusted for the specific page at all.

Yeah, that's what I noticed too. I don't know if that's an observation or a rule, though.

I like your wording and wouldn't add, subtract, or change a word.
